# How to hash files in C#

Tags: c#, hash

1. How do I hash files with C#
2. What is available ? (md5, crc, sha1, etc)
3. Is there an interface i should inherit?

I want to checksum multiple files and store it in a db along with using two of my own checksums/hashes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> 1.) How do i hash files with C#?

You can utilize .NET classes under *[System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx)*

> 2.) What is available?

- [KeyedHashAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.keyedhashalgorithm.aspx)
- [MD5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx)
- [RIPEMD160](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ripemd160.aspx)
- [SHA1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx)
- [SHA256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256.aspx)
- [SHA384](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha384.aspx)
- [SHA512](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512.aspx)

> 3.) Is there an interface i should inherit?

No you don't have to.
Take a look at [HashAlgorithm.Create(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wet69s13.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Snippet

```
byte[] result; 
SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(); 
using(FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"file.txt"))
{
   result = sha.ComputeHash(fs);
}
```

See also [SHA1CryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1cryptoserviceprovider.aspx) or [MD5CryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider.aspx).

CRC is not available -- it's more efficient to create your own.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve with the hashes? If you're trying to actually guarantee that nobody maliciously altered the files, *please* don't implement your own checksum or hash. You'll probably make some mistake and someone will be able to tamper with a file and have the checksums still match. Use a good hash function like SHA-256.