# Generate predictable random numbers C#

Tags: c#, .net

I would like the generate random numbers - except given the same seed, they should always be the same. How could this be done?

e.g. Given the seed 'I like turtles' it should generate a number e.g. 1234 no matter when/how many times it was called. I need this for a security application.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060961/seeding-a-pseudo-random-number-generator-in-c-sharp

Comment: You know predictable random is an oxymoron.

Comment: `var random = new Random("I like turtles".GetHash())`

Comment: so you need some sort of hash?

Comment: Sounds scary. "predictable random numbers" combined with "security application". Rule number one of security: don't do it yourself. There are a lot of very good libraries available.

Comment: Are you trying to make a process that is reversible?

Comment: I have made something that gets a fingerprint of a machine, the predicable random number means the fingerprint won't randomly change, however a hacker would have to write some C#/decompile/recompile to find the value of the random number (hence a little more effort).

Comment: @James It's called "hash" as others said. And if you don't know what hash is chances are your "security" will rather be "obscurity" and probably done incorrectly. Read some more about this type of things, don't reinvent the wheel by making it square

Comment: @StenPetrov As I said in my previous comment, the aim of this is to create a value that could only (easily) be replicated by decomiling/recompiling code - putting most hackers off. There are loads of online hash generators - meaning it's trivial to generate one to simulate what my fingerprint code would do; hence my need for a custom hasher or even simpler, a seeded, predictable random number. I am perfectly aware what a hash is.

Comment: @James ... but to get to the parts they need to hash they also have to decompile your code, making your efforts futile. By adding a (weak) custom hash function you're not increasing the level of difficulty to break your protection. Somehow your bank manages to get by on standard algorithms.

Comment: @StenPetrov Okay, the point is, in this case, if I were to use a normal hash alg, they (hackers) could spot that in a decompile then use an online hash site to get the same output as my fingerprint. Whereas, my much weaker hash alg will require them to decompile my code (to find it) and then recompile it after to get it to spit out values (much more difficult). My bank doesn't rely on .NET client side apps luckily.

Comment: @James and you imagine the recompiling to be a difficult step? And you think just because it's a .NET app that can be decompiled it's less secure? You need to read some more about security, start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is precisely how pseudo random number generators (PRNGs) work. When seeded the same way, they yield the same sequence of pseudo random numbers.

Take a look at the documentation for the constructor of the [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ctssatww.aspx) class:

> Providing an identical seed value to different Random objects causes each instance to produce identical sequences of random numbers.

Only do note that PRNGs use numeric seeds rather than strings, as per your example in the question. And if you need a cryptographically secure PRNG, then you'll need to use a class other than `Random`, although the same principles regarding seeds apply.

Comment: +0.  Isn't relevant for the OP's needs

Comment: @SamIam I don't understand what you mean

Comment: This is what led the answer for me. It would be nice to have one line of code though :)

Comment: @James Why would code help? I like answers that explain things.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just think `var random = new Random("I like turtles".GetHash())` is a nice example to have in there. Up to you.

Comment: @James I'm not sure that's such a great example. Because a different string can yield the same hash value. And presumably you want different seeds to yield different sequences. I'm not really sure what your application is, and you mentioned security, so I don't want to give code and advice that I'm not confident is accurate and appropriate to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class will generate the same sequence of numbers, if you supply it with the same seed.

If you just want to return a predictable number from a given string, use a [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622900/c-sharp-hashes).

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing security, You'd really be better served by using a library, but if you absolutely must do it yourself...

It looks like you'd rather compute a hash code.

[here is some information on generating a MD5 hash code from a string](http://www.etechplanet.com/blog/generate-md5-hash-code-from-a-string-using-c.aspx)

Here is the code sample on that page

```
public static  string CalculateMD5Hash(string strInput)
{
  MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
  byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strInput);
  byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);            

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();           
  for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)           
  {               
    sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2")); 
  }         
  return sb.ToString();       
}
```